# How to structure imports inside project to work for both scripts and modules?

Tags: python, import, python-module

I have a rather simple setup:

```
[FOLDER]
   |-> [Lib]
          __init__.py    (__all__=["modA","modB"])
          modA.py        (contains class named classA)
          modB.py        (contains class named classB + from modA import classA)
          test1.py       (from Lib.modA import classA
                          from Lib.modB import classB)
   |-> [example]
          test2.py       (import sys
                          sys.path.append("../")
                          from Lib.modA import classA
                          from Lib.modB import classB)
```

Running `test1.py` from the Lib folder works perfectly without errors. Running `test2.py` from the example folder on the other hand requires the sys-patch to find `Lib` at all; however, it then crashes with `No module named modA` tracing back to the `from modA import classA` in `modB.py` via `from Lib.modB import classB` in `test2.py`.

How is one supposed to define an import in a module such that it will also work irrespective of the possible location of any future script that may use/import said module?

Comment: Make the lib an actual package you can import?

Comment: The import paths should be set by the environment – via installation, PYTHONPATH, or similar – not by the program itself – via ``sys.path`` or similar. The latter is only for metaprogramming and getting things to work on a tight deadline at 2 AM.

Comment: FWIW (gonna ignore this in an answer) I don't see how ``test1.py`` would work either. It uses ``modA.py`` by *both* ``Lib.modA`` and just ``modA``. This will only "work" when manually tinkering with import paths, and leads to subtly incorrect program state because things actually exist twice.

Comment: @Sayse & MisterMiyagi, that it actually is, but I'm currently developing this package, which makes the idea of installations and packages a bit circular

Comment: @MisterMiyagi test1.py only uses modA once as I read it. It importst modA from lib.modA(.py)

Comment: Note that one can [install a package as editable](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#install-editable), which is suitable for development as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python programs should be thought of as *packages* and *modules*, not as *directories* and *files*. While there is some overlap, packages and modules are more restrictive but also better encapsulated as a result.

Mixing both – say by manually modifying `sys.path` – should only be done as a last resort.

TLDR:

- Use qualified imports based on the package:
  `from Lib.modA import classA`/`from .modA import classA` instead of `from modA import classA` .
- Use the environment for discovery:
  Add search paths via `PYTHONPATH` instead of `sys.path`.

---

#### Start by deciding which ones are the *top-level* packages.

This is the point where we go from "directories/files" to "package". Notably, we cannot go "above" the top-level later on, so it should contain everything we need. However, we cannot remove anything "below" either, so it should be a tight enough selection.

In the example we could go as low as treating `modA` and siblings as their own module-package, and as high as `FOLDER` encompassing the entire project.

```
[FOLDER]
|-> [Lib]
|   |-> modA.py
:   :
```

It is reasonable to pick `Lib` since it represents a self-contained part. Going higher to `FOLDER` would be excessive, going lower to `modA` and siblings would break their relation as belonging together.

*Everything under the top-level package folder now belongs to the package.*

Prominently, `FOLDER/Lib/modA.py` is now the module `Lib.modA`. It is not `FOLDER.Lib.modA`, nor just `modA`.

---

#### Import package content only with absolute or relative qualified names.

Now that the top-level is established, all `import` statements must be made with regard to it. Refer to modules by their *qualified* name only, even when two modules share a more common parent:

```py
# Lib.modB
# okay, fully qualified import
from Lib.modA import classA
# broken, unqualified import
from modA import classA
```

In order to avoid typing out the entire fully qualified name, one can use a *relative* name instead. This reuses the current module name to derive the fully qualified name of the module to import.

```py
# Lib.modB
# okay, relative import
from .modA import classA
```

**Note:** Relative imports are a *package* operation, not a *filesystem* operation. One cannot go beyond the top-level, but descend into package namespaces.

*Everything inside the module is now encapsulated and self-contained.*

All qualified imports will work irrespective of the location of the package itself. As long as the top-level can be imported, everything below it can be imported as well.
Notably, this works irrespective of the location of any future script that may use/import the package.

##### Run packaged code with absolute qualified names

When executing code *inside* a package, Python has to know that the code is part of the package. Thus, it must be run with its absolute qualified named. Use [the -m switch](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) to do so:

```bash
# import and execute Lib.test1
python3 -m Lib.test1
```

---

#### Enable packages via the environment, not the program.

The point of defining a package is getting a single, self-contained entity that represents a library. One could zip up a package or similar, and it would still be a package.
In return, this means that the code itself should not break this abstraction by directly adding/changing directories to search packages.

Instead of having scripts assume the location of the package, the environment - of the script, the user, or the entire machine – should expose the package. There are basically two ways to do this:

- *Announce* the package location as a search location. This is suitable for development as it is flexible but hard to maintain. The [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) is appropriate for this.
- *Move* the package to a search location used by Python. This is suitable for production and distribution as it requires effort but is easy to maintain. [Packaging and using a package manager](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/) is appropriate for this.

Comment: The from .modA import modA does the trick. I'm always amazed how unnecessarily complicated python is design when going beyond absolutely trivial examples. Thanks for the additional info as well. I'll probably need it when finishing things up.

Answer (score 0):

To what I understand, when you are trying to run manually there is no path set as the environment, and when you just do
`python file.py`
python doesn't know in which environment we are running, which is precisely why, we do sys.path.append, to add the sibling directory path to env.

In the case if you are using an IDE like spyder or pycharm. you have an option to set the directory in which your program is located, or in pycharm it creates the whole program as a package where all the paths are handled by IDE.